# implement ssid and bssid in android

Tags: android, wifi

I am making an app in which i have to get `SSID` and `BSSID` of `Android device`.I tried Stack Overflow links but i was unable to find anything relevant.Can anyone help me.I tried the `Wifi` links also but could not found any relevant material. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before trying to search for links on any topic, I always make it a point to go through the `Android Developer Guide`

To implement such an `Application` you can use the [getBSSID](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiInfo.html#getBSSID%28%29) and [getSSID](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiInfo.html#getSSID%28%29) methods.

Here is a [tutorial](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/01/monitor-wifi-status-and-information.html) to start with.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you come across an error **`"Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method"`**, check the developer's site. There are public methods which return an instance of the classes you are not able to access. Those instances can  used in your program.

In this case, check the developer's site : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html

`wifimanager` has public methods which return objects of type `wifiinfo`, like : `getConnectionInfo()`.
You should be able to access those objects without any problem ! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use smth following methods:

```
...
WifiInfo wfInfo = WifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
...
wfInfo.getBSSID();
wfInfo.getSSID();
```

It was just a hint. Actual code will be something like this:

```
//Call system service WifiManager WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

//Get connection information
WifiInfo wfInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();

//Get SSID and BSSID
String BSSID = wfInfo.getBSSID();
String SSID = wfInfo.getSSID();
```

Comment: The above code gives error Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getConnectionInfo() from the type WifiManager